# c# ora-02291 error

Tags: oracle10g, odp.net

This is an odd one...
I have two tables tableA and tableB
tableB has a foreign key in tableA.

I have 2 sprocs, one inserts to tableA, the other to tableB.

using odp.net I run the first sproc, inserting a record into tableA. I can then open SQLPlus and select this record

I then run the second sproc, inserting into tableB.
**It fails with "ora-02291-integrity-constraint-violated-parent-key-not-found"**

I have double, triple, quadruple checked for typos etc... nothing.

To make things even more odd when I do this same operation manually in SQLPlus, with the same sprocs, it works without a problem.

This is killing me 12+ hours looking for something I know has to be simple.
Here are the sprocs.

**SPROCA**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE genData_TestTrackerSegment
  (
    INTX_ID IN IntxSegment.IntxID%TYPE,
    siteid IN INT
  )
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO INTXSEGMENT(INTXID,INTXTYPEID,VERSION,ISPRIVATE,
SEGMENTTYPE,STARTDATETIME,INTXDIRECTION,SITEID)
VALUES(INTX_ID,1,1,0,1,SYSDATE,1,siteid);
COMMIT;
END;
```

**SPROCB**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE genData_TestTrackerPart
  (
    INTX_ID IN IntxSegment.IntxID%TYPE,
    INTX_PART_ID IN INTX_PARTICIPANT.INTX_PART_ID%TYPE,
    INDIVID IN INDIVIDUAL.INDIVID%TYPE,
    CALLID IN INTX_PARTICIPANT.CALLIDKEY%TYPE
  )AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO
INTX_PARTICIPANT(INTXID,INTX_PART_ID,INDIVID,ROLE,
CALLIDKEY,RECORDED,VERSION,STARTDATETIME)
VALUES(INTX_ID,INTX_PART_ID,INDIVID,1,CALLID,1,1,SYSDATE);
COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: What are the types (in DB) of `INTXID` in tableA and in tableB ? to what type are they mapped in your .net code ?

Comment: Database Type : char(22)  
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.DBType : String  
OracleParameter.OracleDBType : Varchar2  
OracleParameter.OracleDBTypeEx : VarChar2

Comment: Are you certain that it's the foreign key referencing INTXSEGMENT.INTXID that is throwing the exception, and not another foreign key constraint? To debug this, I would disable that foreign key, and run the test, and if successful, check the contents of the INTX_PARTICIPANT table to verify the value in the INTXID column.

Comment: Yeah I am more than certain - it is without a shadow of a doubt that FKEY. That being said I fixed this..... This is sooooooo stupid by the way. I was under the (mistaken) assumption that 'named parameters' in ODP.NET meant I did not have to add these parameters in the same order they are referenced in the stored procedure. Long story short - after I re-wrote this about 4 times I modified the order of the parameters and it is now fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I am more than certain - it is without a shadow of a doubt that FKEY.
That being said I fixed this..... This is **sooooooo stupid** by the way.
 I was under the (mistaken) assumption that 'named parameters' in ODP.NET meant I did not have to add these parameters in the same order they are referenced in the stored procedure. Long story short - after I re-wrote this about 4 times I modified the order of the parameters and it is now fixed. –

Answer (score 0):

For me, ORA-02291 error means that one of the FK used is not a valid pk or not an existing pk from the other table.

Just Make sure that each FK inserted in your TABLE is a valid one.